# Unable to run Node.js after installation from source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

I've tried installing Node.js using the following instructions:

`cd /opt`

`wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26.tar.gz`

`cd node-v0.10.26`

`./configure`

`make`

`make install`

However, once the installation has completed (and with no errors at that), I'm unable to run `node --version`. I'm currently running on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and have tried multiple ways to install Node.js that all result in the same issue. Could it be a PATH issue, or something else? I'm new to Node.js, and would love to learn any tips or tricks that you may have to get this up and running.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did `make install` copy the installation files? `/opt`seems unlikely unless you passed `--prefix=/opt/node-v0.10.26`. Also, `/opt/` probably isn't on your `$PATH`. Try `echo $PATH` to find out to find out all the directories on your `$PATH`.  Also, you forgot to mention the issue you get on `node --version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without giving it a `--prefix` the default installation directory is in `/usr/local/` tree.

So make sure you have `/usr/local/bin` in your path (may even require a logout/login in case) or try with full path such as:

> /usr/local/bin/node --version